# Swing JTable is throwing java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: privateKey

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using Windows 7 , trying to run this simple below program , but always its throwing Exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: privateKey
    at java.awt.Component.initIDs(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.streamer.Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

SSCCE is

```
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Source Demo");
         final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {
                    "Id", "Name", "Desg" }, 0);
            final JTable table = new JTable(model);
            JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(scrollpane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            Vector vec = new Vector();
            vec.add("1122");
            vec.add("Iraneee");
            vec.add("Dev");
            model.insertRow(0, vec);
    }
}
```

Comment: final JTable table = new JTable(model); line 16

Comment: it works for me without any issue

Comment: Sounds like your compiled classes are not all up-to-date. Try to clean and rebuild.